# Nano disable help mode by default

Tags: nano

Is there a way to disable the help mode in Nano by default? I know I can disable it by pressing the Meta + X key, but I'd like it to be disabled when I start Nano.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Start with `nano -x`. This, and much more about `nano`, can be found in `man nano`. If you get tired of typing `-x` all the time, consider setting up an `alias` for `nano -x` like this:

`alias nano="nano -x"`

Another way to permanently disable the help line is to put a line:

`set nohelp`

in the file `~/.nanorc`. If you don't have this file, create one. See `man nanorc` for more.